# If there are y blocks in each street $v_i$ with $0≤i≤x$, why the sum of the blocks isn't y(1+x)?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image]

In the solution, I don't understand the part $y_0+y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_x=y$. Since there are y+1 parallel lines, there are y blocks in each vertical street $v_0, v_1, ..., v_x$. So $y_0+y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_x$ equals not y, but yx.

[image]

Source: A Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates: Counting Strategies by Titu Andreescu, Zuming Feng.

[image]

Comment: @trueblueanil two. BTW, what does it have to do with my question?

Comment: $y+1$ parallel lines, $y$ blocks in **each** vertical street.

Answer (score 2):

You write:

> In the solution, I don't understand the part $y_0+y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_x=y$.
>
> Since there are $y+1$ parallel lines, there are $y$ blocks in each vertical street $v_0, v_1, ..., v_x$. So $y_0+y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_x$ equals not $y$, but $yx$.

You’re counting all of the blocks on all of the vertical streets (though that is actually $(x+1)y$, as in the red addition to the page, not $xy$); ). That is, you’re assuming that $y_k=y$ for $k=0,\ldots,x$, as if $y_k$ were the whole number of blocks on the street $v_k$. It’s not: $y_k$ is the number of blocks on street $v_k$ **that are part of the path** that we’re considering at the moment. The point is that it doesn’t matter which path from $A$ to $B$ we’re considering. All movement upward is along one of the $x+1$ streets $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_x$. If $y_k$ is the number of blocks that we move up while on street $v_k$, then $$y_0+y_1+\ldots+y_x$$ is the total number of blocks that we move upward. We start at $A$ at height $0$ and finish at $B$ at height $y$, so we must move upward a total of $y$ blocks, and therefore

$$y_0+y_1+\ldots+y_x=y\;.$$